# c# How can i start a process multiple times?

Tags: c#, process

I need a script in c# so i can try multiple cases in a console program. The script works just fine at the first case but in the second case it wont let me run again the process. this is the code:

```
try{ 

        string[] cases= Directory.GetFiles(CasesDir);
        string[] singleCase;
        foreach(string file in cases){

            p.Start();
            StreamWriter stdwriter= p.StandardInput;
            singleCase=File.ReadAllLines(file);

            foreach(string line in singleCase){
                stdwriter.WriteLine(line);
            }

            stdwriter.Close();
            p.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine( p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() );
            p.CloseMainWindow();
            p.Close();

        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        Console.WriteLine("=X EXE "+e.Message);
    }
```

Comment: "Does not work" has never been a sufficient problem description. Please be specific what is happening or not happening.

Comment: You're likely just stuck on `p.WaitForExit` your loop won't continue until it's done waiting

Comment: Maybe has something to do with re-using `p`. I would write a function `RunTestCase(string someParam)` and call that in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i tried to start my process after "p.Close()". So the process didnt start over for some reason. The final code looks like this:

```
string[] cases= Directory.GetFiles(CasesDir), solCases=Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(CasesDir,"sol"));
        string[] singleCase,singleSolCase;
        string salida;
        int i=0;

foreach(string file in cases){

            Console.WriteLine("\nCase "+(i+1).ToString());

            p.Start();
            singleCase=File.ReadAllLines(file);

            foreach(string line in singleCase){
                p.StandardInput.WriteLine(line);
            }

            singleCase=null;

            p.StandardInput.Close();
            p.WaitForExit();

            singleSolCase=File.ReadAllLines(solCases[i]);

            foreach(string line in singleSolCase){
                if(p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream){
                    Console.WriteLine("=X Output incomplete");
                    break;
                }
                testerOutput=p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                if(string.Compare(salida,line)!=0){
                    Console.WriteLine("=X Wrong Output\n"+"Solution: "+line+"\nOutput: "+salida);
                }
            }

            singleSolCase=null;
            i++;

        }
```